# Send writable stream as an attachment node express

Tags: node.js, express, exceljs

I am creating an xlsx workbook using the module [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#create-a-workbook) and then I would like to send it as an attachment through my express middleware.

I create and save my workbook in a stream using the following code as shown in documentation of the module

```
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('test.xlsx');    
    // write to a stream
    workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
        .then(function() {
            // done
    });
```

where stream is a writable stream.

My problem is that I can't understand how to handle the stream in order to send it. 
Trying to pipe it to res  `stream.pipe(res)` gives my an error that is not readable stream to pipe it.

What is the best course of action for me now?

p.s. I could save it into a file in the server and then read the file and send it through express. That would not help me as the attachment is not needed afterwards, and is a workaround which I do not like.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the stream you can do the following to send it as attachment in express:

`res.attachment('yourfile.xlsx');
stream.pipe(res);`

Comment: As I wrote above stream.pipe(res) gives an error.
"Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable"

Comment: Any chance of a little more code so we can see the context? Such as how you create the stream.

Comment: I added the creation of the stream.  I am open to suggestions if you think I am not starting properly.

Comment: you need to do `createReadStream` to get the stream to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exceljs' default streaming XLSX Writer.

```
// construct a streaming XLSX workbook writer with styles and shared strings
var options = {
    stream: res // stream to server response
};
var workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
```

According to [the document](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#streaming-io), the constructor takes an optional options object with the following fields:

- `stream`: Specifies a writable stream to write the XLSX workbook to.
- `filename`: If stream not specified, this field specifies the path to a
  file to write the XLSX workbook to.